# Laravel user image showing everywhere except "edit" page

Tags: laravel

i am using `<img src="{{Auth::user()->image}}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-32 img-circle mr-3">`to show the user image. it is working fine on all other pages. but when I click edit it doesn't show the the image. the path then changes to **http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit-client/backend/images/user/1740499121420107.png** while it should be **http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/images/user/1740499121420107.png**
an extra "edit-page" is inserted in the image path.
in my blade file I am using these codes to redirect to the edit pages

```
<a href="{{ route('EditClient',['id' => $client->id]) }}" type="button">Edit</a>
```

or,`<a href="{{ URL::to('/edit-gallery/' . $gallery->id) }}" type="button">Edit</a>`

in my web.php

```
Route::get('/edit-user/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\backend\UserController::class, 'EditUser'])->name('EditUser');
```

Comment: As always, add a slash `/` in front of your image path, so the path is taken from the webserver's "DocumentRoot"/topmost folder instead of the current folder. `<img src="/{{Auth::user()->image}}"`. Or use the `asset` helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is saved in public directory you can use `asset(Auth::user()->image)`.